# Fast results from a large SQL "IN" clause and a millions of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, select

In Postgres
Consider a table with 30 million rows, one column of which is Country. All countries are represented, so roughly 200 different countries. There's an app that allows a user to select any number of countries and the app is to return all the rows.

So the basic solution looks something like this (where the app/user has selected the 4 countries in the collection):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Country IN ('italy','france', 'sweden', 'canada');
```

What's a more performant solution?

Comment: Why would you think this is not performant?

Comment: when we try it, it's really slow lol

Comment: The issue is probably that you are returning lots and lots of data.  There are only a couple hundred countries, so your query is probably returning at least several hundred thousand rows -- if not millions.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a B-tree index on the column, that query is the most performant solution.